# Initialise simple_form object inline

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, form

Using Rails 4 and a simple form, I'm rendering a couple of forms outside of their native controllers. Rather than scattering initialisers through my controllers, I wondered if it is cleaner to do the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @event_submission || EventSubmission.new do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do stuff like that myself sometimes, but I'm not proud of it.

Strictly speaking it is the controller's responsibility to set up the new record. The controller should be be the sole source of whatever (primary) data the view needs. Instantiating a new record is business logic, not presentation logic.

In a similar vein, if we consider a simple blogging app, it'd be fine for the view to access secondary data, like:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

But I think you'd agree that it absolutely *shouldn't* be doing something like:

```
<% Post.find(params[:id]).comments.each do |comment %> <!-- please don't do this -->
```

Your code basically the same as the latter of those two examples. Although it seems less extreme, in both cases the view is doing the job of the controller.

Also: Assuming a typical Rails setup, your form is in its own partial, and you include it in both the `edit` and `new` views when rendering. Now, when editing, the `@event_submission` variable absolutely *should* exist - it should be set by the controller. It makes no sense for the form to create it. And when one "invocation" of the form requires it, it makes no sense for the other invocation to make it optional. So basically, the *form* requires an `@event_submission` variable - doesn't matter if it's new or not.

Letting for form instantiate the record also opens the door for hidden bugs and unintended behavior. If you navigate to `/event_submissions/123/edit` (or whatever the path is), but the controller somehow *doesn't* set the `@event_submission` to be edited, the form will just create its own. This means that:

1. You won't get an error (though you should!) because the form absorbed it. Your tests may even pass.
2. The form will be blank, which it shouldn't be when editing.
3. And since it's inferred that a form for a new record should point to the create action, if you submit the form, you're creating a new record when all you wanted was to edit one.

Everything works, there are no errors, but it's not at all doing what it's supposed to. Have fun debugging :)

Besides, your code works for HTML via ERB. But if you want a different format, or use a different templating language, you may not get away with it anymore. Since you'll then have to do the initialization in the controller anyway, you might as always do that.

Answer (score 2):

As Flambino says, we've all been there, I don't think it's a big deal. Note however that if you wanted to do it "right", you wouldn't need to write initializers on every controller. Just a `before_action` on the parent controller. Let's say you have a `PublicController`:

```
class PublicController
  before_filter :load_event_submission

  def load_event_submission
    @event_submission = EventSubmission.new
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. Alternatively, just declare the `load_event_submission` method in the parent controller, but only add the `before_filter` to the controllers that need it. Of course, if _all_ the controllers need it, then yeah, put that in the parent controller as well, of course.